# Visibility of embedded private interfaces in Go

Tags: go, interface, visibility, embedding

If I embed an interface with a lowercase name (private) into another interface with an uppercase name (public), I assume that code outside of the defining package cannot see the embedded private interface. Is this assumption correct?

```
type b interface {
    G() int
}

type A interface {
    F() string
    b
}
```

Code outside of the defining package cannot "see" the embedded `b`, correct? Outside code cannot call `G` through an instance of `A`.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Embedding unexported interface in interface

Interface embedding in interface is nothing more than merging the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of the embedded interface into the embedder, so it becomes part of the method set of the embedder type. It doesn't matter if the embedded interface type is exported or not. Quoting from [Spec: Interface types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)

> An interface `T` may use a (possibly qualified) interface type name `E` in place of a method specification. This is called *embedding* interface `E` in `T`; it adds all (exported and non-exported) methods of `E` to the interface `T`.

All that happens in your code is that `A` will be an interface with 2 methods: `F() string` and `G() int`. There won't be a "field" like `A.b` because `A` is an interface type, not a struct. So this isn't particularly "interesting".

How can you try it?

Create a folder `subplay` in any package, `subplay.go`:

```
package subplay

type b interface {
    G() int
}

type A interface {
    F() string
    b
}
```

Create another `go` file that imports this `subplay`, e.g. `play.go`:

```
package main

import "play/subplay"

func main() {
    var a subplay.A
    a.G()
}
```

And it compiles. Runtime panic occurs though because `a` is not initialized (or rather left being `nil`), but if it would be, the `a.G()` call would not panic.

With the following additions there will be no run-time panic:

In `subplay.go`, add:

```
type aimpl struct{}

func (aimpl) F() string { return "aimpl.F() called" }
func (aimpl) G() int    { return 1 }

func NewA() A {
    return aimpl{}
}
```

And in `play.go`:

```
func main() {
    var a subplay.A
    a = subplay.NewA()
    a.G()
}
```

The above code compiles and runs, and does not panic.

Also note that you can create a type in another package that implements `subplay.A`, you do not need to refer to `subplay.b`, because all that matters is the method set. The following `another` type also implements `subplay.A`, you can place this in `play.go`:

```
type another struct{}

func (another) F() string { return "aimpl.F() called" }
func (another) G() int    { return 1 }

func main() {
    var a subplay.A
    a = another{}
    a.G()
}
```

This again compiles and runs without run-time panic.

### Embedding unexported interface in struct

A similar and more interesting case would be to embed an unexported struct (or an interface) type in a struct (and not in an interface), which "truly" creates an `A.b` field. Moreover, fields and methods of the embedded type get promoted to the embedder as if they would be fields or methods of the embedder. Quoting from [Spec: Struct types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> A field or method `f` of an embedded field in a struct `x` is called *promoted* if `x.f` is a legal [selector](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) that denotes that field or method `f`.
>
> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they cannot be used as field names in [composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) of the struct.

Code outside of the defining package cannot refer to the embedded field `A.b`, this is correct, but code outside of the defining package *can* call the promoted `A.G()` method because this identifier is not lower-cased, so the restriction does not apply to it.

The restriction for non-exported identifiers is enforced by the compiler when you attempt to refer to them. Writing `a.b.G()` from another package is a compile-time error, because you are referring to a non-exported identifier (`a.b`). When you write `a.G()`, you are not referring to any non-exported identifiers, only to the exported `a.G` identifier, so it is allowed.

Comment: That is really interesting. I would have thought that `G` would be hidden because of being "behind" `b`. Thanks.

Comment: "but if it would be (along with the `A.b` field), `a.b.G()` would be called no problem." - What do you mean here. Its not clear

Comment: @aerokite The phrasing wasn't completely right, edited it. I mean that in my example `a` is `nil`. If you would assign a non-`nil` value to it (that implements `subplay.A`), then the `a.G()` call would not panic. See edited answer.

Comment: @Ralph Completely reworked my answer, please check the new version.

Comment: The fact that public promoted values can be referenced outside of the defining package could be problematic if there is an ambiguity because of two embedded private types having the same name. Thanks for the thorough answer.

Comment: @Ralph Please note that the spec states _"...promoted if `x.f` is a **legal** [selector](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)..."_. If your struct embeds 2 different types both having a field or method with the same name, then `x.f` will **not** be legal, and the `x.f` selector will be a compile-time error.

Comment: Understood. This all started because I had a private interface that contained several private embedded interfaces. I did not want to change the embedded interfaces to public because I was too lazy to write comments for them. :-) In my case it does not matter because there is no name overlap. I can keep them private.