# Go use struct as interface without implementing all methods

Tags: unit-testing, go, methods, interface

For example i have dao with 20 methods.

```
type UserDao interface {
    GetUser() (User, error)
    GetUsers() ([]User, error)
    ...
}
```

And i want create mock for tests and use only one method.

```
type UserDaoMock struct { }

fucn (UserDaoMock) GetUser() (User, error) {
    return User{}
}
```

There is a way to don't implements other methods before using UserDaoMock as a UserDao in tests? Tell the compiler that this is how it should be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Embed the `UserDao` interface in your mock struct, so it will have all the methods promoted. Implement only the methods you need (the methods that will actually be called):

```
type UserDao interface {
    GetUser() (User, error)
    GetUsers() ([]User, error)
}

type UserDaoMock struct {
    UserDao
}

func (UserDaoMock) GetUser() (User, error) {
    return User{}, nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
var dao UserDao
dao = UserDaoMock{}
fmt.Println(dao.GetUser())
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/VebtPnbtY4a)):

```
{} <nil>
```

Note that calling any other methods would panic of course, because the embedded `UserDao` field is `nil`, so there is no real implementation behind them. But `UserDaoMock` does implement `UserDao`, and the `GetUser()` method is implemented and is callable.

See related question to detect which methods are callable: [Go reflection with interface embedded in struct - how to detect "real" functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988632/go-reflection-with-interface-embedded-in-struct-how-to-detect-real-functions/61448767#61448767)

Other related questions:

[Is it possible to define an anonymous interface implementation in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54128210/is-it-possible-to-define-an-anonymous-interface-implementation-in-go/54128329#54128329)

[Visibility of embedded private interfaces in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48906699/visibility-of-embedded-private-interfaces-in-go/48906742#48906742)